# What is the Black Tab?

Tags: blacktab

I've recently seen references to a black tab. E.g.

- BT link to org: https://na2.salesforce.com/00D300000xxxxxx?blacktaboid=00D300000xxxxxx
- BT link to managed package: https://na2.salesforce.com/033400000xxxxxx?blacktaboid=00D300000xxxxxx&tab=PackageComponents

Is this some internal Salesforce functionality?

The extra query string parameters seem to have no affect for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a tab available only to Salesforce employees, primarily higher tier support I believe, that they use to enable/disable specific features or adjust limits in customer orgs.  See this blog post for a few details: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/10/12/favorite-salesforce-black-tab-features/

Some of the functionality that can be enabled/disabled according to that blog:

- Enable API for PE orgs
- Disable auto-number fields from being incremented by unit tests
- Allow editing of LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, CreatedDate and CreatedBy fields
- Disable security tokens

Some of the limits that can be adjusted according to that blog:

- Increase Apex Code limit beyond 2MB
- Increase standard daily e-mail limit
- Increase the allowed number of roll-up summary fields on an object
- Increase the allowed number of external ID fields on an object
- Increase limit on Web-to-Lead submissions

Comment: In addition there's also a much more restricted version of the black tab, "partner black tab" available to registered ISVs. This allows them (us?) to login to subscriber orgs if users have explicitly granted login access and to view an overview of your org if you have a package installed (that part doesn't require consent, looks like this) which looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/aAmii.jpg

Comment: Hadn't even noticed that tab was black as well.

Comment: Internally salesforce called it "partnerBT" and according to them it uses the same technology as their black tab, so I figured it was worth a mention.

Answer (score 6):

To add to E.J.'s answer, it is also used by some Sales Engineers, Sales Support Engineers, and the Demo team to increase limits or turn on pre-release features for pre-sales and event demos. It's also used to enable "DOT"ing of orgs, which allows the data and config to be cloned (very useful for demo orgs)

Answer (score 6):

Mainly SFDC blacktab is used by internal Salesforce.com IT.  Its the backend to every other orgs back end.  I used to work for their support and used it everyday.  It doesnt look any different than a normal org really, just a little search bar and the ability to hop from server to server via one click logins.